# How hover event works on super-hands components?

Tags: aframe

I'm developing a menu using a-plane and a-entity with text attribute. It uses super-hand as controller. But I can't receive hover event when I link hover event on controller to receive event from a-plane, and vice versa. ¿Can you help me understand how it works?

Comment: can you provide a link to the docs where does the `collide` event comes from? The [hand-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/hand-controls.html#sidebar) dont have it, do you mean [the one mentioned here](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html#events)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. hands-controllers don't have collide control. Let me reformulate the question with super-hands components.

Comment: You just wanna "hit" a button with the controller?

Comment: Yes, just "hit" or "touch" the option in the menu.